# T4. Error: An expression block evaluated as Null

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, t4

I've added template.tt file that looks like:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class <#= this.ClassName#>
    {       

    }
}

<#+
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
#>
```

I'm receiving error:

```
An expression block evaluated as Null
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ToStringHelper.ToStringWithCulture(Object objectToConvert)...
```

What should I do to avoid seeing these messages?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the ClassName property is null. One way to fix the error would be to change the code in the class feature block to:

```
<#+
    private string className = "";

    public string ClassName {
        get { return className; }
        set { className = value; }
    }
#>
```

Comment: On the whole, a property isn't adding much value over just a member variable in a T4 template.  I'd skip the property entirely and simply call the member variable 'ClassName'.  I think it's necessary to reevaluate the value of some everyday coding rules when creating non-reusable code in templates.  Although you're writing code in C#, think of it more as a scripting environment.

Answer (score 3):

I assume, you want to generate something like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class MyClass
    {       

    }
}
```

The issue in the code is in expression block you are reffering to a variable `<#= this.ClassName#>` that doesn't exist in the class feature block. Modify the code as below.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class <#= this.ClassName #> //Expression Block
    {       
    }
}

<#+ //Class feature block
    public string ClassName = "MyClass";
#>
```

Comment: Actually, it does exist, as a property, but its value is null, as it hasn't been initialized.